# Overload "require" and/or "fs" in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, require

I'm new to Javascript and nodejs. I'm developing a nodejs app using expressjs. I'm trying to do two things:-

1. I want to load my modules from a database instead of the file
   system.
2. I want to serve web pages, templates, etc. from a database
       instead of the file system as well.

To solve the 1st item I was considering writing my own custom loader. I could still load 3rd party modules from the file system using "require" and my own modules from a database using "myRequire" like this:-

```
var myDb = require('mydb');
var user = myRequire('/alocation/user')(myDb);
```

I don't know what the code inside of "myRequire" would look like and have struggled to find examples. Any examples?

For the 2nd item I could obviously write my own module for reading/writing content to the database but how do I integrate it into the nodejs/express framework?  That is, for example, `res.render('user')` that will load from the database instead of the file system?

I guess I could do my own template processing to get a string and call  `res.send(processedTemplateString)` but it would be nice to leverage express.

One (extreme) solution is to overload the 'fs' module so that all file system actions are caught and redirected to read/write to the database. This would also redirect "require" to load from the database and I could also take advantage of its caching for my own modules. But since 'fs' is built-in I don't even know if I can do this (or want to do it - sounds dangerous).